# How to redirect after login using entrust package in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5.4, entrust

It's not working auto redirect role based after login.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

    /*Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('general');
    });*/

    Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
    Route::get('/admin', [
        'as' => 'admin.index',
        'middleware' => 'role:admin',
        'uses' => function () {
            return view('admin.index');
        }
    ]);
    Route::resource('roles', 'RolesController');
    Route::get('/general', [
        'as' => 'general.index',
        'middleware' => 'role:general',
        'uses' => function () {
            return view('general.index');
        }
    ]);
});
```

Comment: Show some details it's not clear what do you want

Comment: Dear, thanks for comment.

Comment: Dear, I have a login form. When i login to my site, I want to role based redirect page open. For Example- admin and user two roles. when admin login redirect to admin directory and user login redirect to user directory.

Comment: I understand but what is the error you get ?

Comment: There is no error but redirect to home page. But not go admin or user page.

Comment: try put the line `Route::resource('users', 'UserController');` to the last.